# Uploading PDF file and validates the size not more than 2mb

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

Any sample codes guys about the uploading a PDF file only that validates the size not more than 2mb. If the file is more than 2mb the system will not accept the file or just delete the file on the form so the user will upload again the right file(less than or equal to 2mb). Thank you so much guys. and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `fileInput.files[0].size` doesn't lie

Comment: you need to add php or some server side tag to this question, or you can use some file input plugin that validates it before submission like this one http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Answer (score 0):

You may try this JavaScript code with your html file.

```
function SubmitForm() {
                    var imgpath = document.getElementById("fileUpload").value;
                    if(imgpath=="")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("lblError").innerHTML = "No file was chosen before clicking on Upload button. Please chose a file first.";
                        return;
                    }

                    var allowedFiles = [".pdf"];
                    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
                    var lblError = document.getElementById("lblError");
                    var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(" + allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$");
                    if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                        lblError.innerHTML = "Please upload files having extensions: <b>" + allowedFiles.join(', ') + "</b> only.";
                        return;
                    }
                    if (fileUpload.files[0].size > 2097152){
                        lblError.innerHTML = "File size is more than 2 MB.";
                        return;
                    }
                    lblError.innerHTML = "";
                    return;

                    lblError.innerHTML = "File Upload in Progress.......";
                    document.form.action = "upload_filedata.asp";
                    document.form.submit();

                }
```

And Call this `"JavaScript:SubmitForm();"` with you `Submit` button.